# Inline for loop Python. Checking every member of a list to another list inline

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a question I've been meaning to ask for awhile now. I have some code and I am trying to check every item of a referenced list towards another list, all of this INLINE. For example:

```
if int(word[:-1])>=1 and int(word[:-1])<=31 and for word in LIST1, word in LIST2:
                day = word[:-1]
```

More specifically, this is part of data-scraping program to filter out various fields of data such as days and months.

```
months = ["January","February",etc......]
days = ["monday,","tuesday,","wednesday,","thursday,","friday,","saturday,","sunday,"]
if word.lower() in days and For i in line.split(), months.contains(i)
```

So for example, in list1 I have every day of week. If LIST2 contains ANY of the (not all) days of the week this would evaluate to true. Does anyone know a slick way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain your question with a sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if set(list2) & set(list1):
   print "there is something in list2 that matches something in list1"

print "The days in list2 are", set(list2) & set(list1)
```

etc

Comment: OK, so inline, I could just specify each list as a set and use the & to return a boolean?

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell strictly speaking, the & returns a set.   The set evaluates to True in a boolean context if it has members.